# Is it possible to install lanmessenger on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

On previous Ubuntu versions like 18.04 LTS I was able to install [LAN Messenger](https://lanmessenger.github.io/).

But on modern Ubuntu 20.04 LTS it is not installable with the following messages:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://github.com/lanmessenger/lanmessenger/releases/download/v1.2.37/lmc_1.2.37_x86_64_min.deb
sudo apt-get install ./lmc_1.2.37_x86_64_min.deb

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'lmc' instead of './lmc_1.2.37_x86_64_min.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lmc : Depends: libssl1.0.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of an [issue with old libssl1.0.0 package](https://github.com/lanmessenger/lanmessenger/issues/55), but LAN Messenger is installable with below workaround:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://github.com/lanmessenger/lanmessenger/releases/download/v1.2.37/lmc_1.2.37_x86_64_min.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.7_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.7_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5

sudo apt-get install ./lmc_1.2.37_x86_64_min.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is working fine but, **libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.7_amd64.deb** this package is not there (404 Error i am getting)

To resolve that i used below steps

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://github.com/lanmessenger/lanmessenger/releases/download/v1.2.37/lmc_1.2.37_x86_64_min.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb --fix-broken
sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5

sudo apt-get install ./lmc_1.2.37_x86_64_min.deb
```

Comment: if you got 404 error then please use below commands

`wget -c https://1lint.com/downloads/lmc/lmc_1.2.37_x86_64_min.deb`



`wget -c https://1lint.com/downloads/lmc/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb`